# How do I invoke button click function in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have got the following code in html

```
      <div class="functionitem" id="viewresult"><span class="button"><span>
      <input type="button" class="form_button" value="  View"></span></span>
       </div>
```

So I try to using the following jquery click function to invoke a method when the button get clicked, this is what I have done

```
      $("#viewresult:button").click(function () { 
      //methods
          });
```

But it's not working, what did I do wrong, please help, thanks

Comment: What does the colon do? Try `#viewresult input[type=button]`

Comment: @tjameson It's a special jQuery selector: http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/

Comment: since you have only one input element in the container with id 'viewresult' you don't need to use button you can just use input like   `$('#viewresult input').click(funtion());`

Comment: @Digital Plane - Hrm... I'd recommend using straight CSS3 selectors where possible.

Comment: @Ehtesham - Being explicit is good for future-proofing.

Comment: @tjameson True, even the jQuery docs recommend using `filter`.

Answer (score 5):

Your selector is wrong. It is trying to find a button with id `viewresult`. Putting a space between the two will indicate that the button should be a descendant of the `viewresult` element.

```
 $("#viewresult :button").click(function () { 
  //methods
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave a space in your selector. `:button` is a descendant of `#viewitem`, not a qualifying property. e.g.

```
$('#viewitem :button').click(...);
```

That says "a :button that falls under the #viewitem element"

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#viewresult input:button").click(function () { 
     //methods
 });
```